# JQuery Scrolling event fire many time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my scenario I have a web page which will navigate through using `mousewheel` and `scrollbar`. I have fixed the `mousewheel` problem.... But the problem where I use the `scrollbar` it will navigate to the end or go to the first it depending on the `scrollbar` you pressed `up` or `down`.
I know the error is `$(window).scroll(function)` here due I navigate from `Div 1` to `Div 2` which will fire the event a lot of times when the scroll bar moving.

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8u5p12ue/1)

The problem is where i when i scroll using the bar beside `down` or `up`. It will trigger until the end of my `onscroll event`.

Is it possible when i press the scrollbar once only trigger once ?
An alternative way i know is hide the `scrollbar` and design a `fixed position button up and down` will resolve this problem but is it possible to do this with `default scrollbar/overflow` ?

Comment: Check this out http://lions-mark.com/jquery/scrollTo/ | https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

Tried your fiddle. When using mouse wheel, it kept pending between headers 4 and 3 after I reached the 4th one. When I removed the `$(window).scroll()` function, it worked perfectly, both down and up.

The scrollbar, however, is quite a complicated issue - when you click/tap and drag, you simply can't "steal" the scrollbar from your pointer/finger - the user keeps dragging, yet you're trying to reposition the scrollbar/content forcibly. I don't think this is a good idea (from the UX point of view).

Not sure if it fits your requirements but in case I'd want to fully control the content, I'd completely remove the `scrollbar` in `CSS` and then use the mousewheel or swipe functions to control it.

Comment: Thanks @psylogic for the edit - could you please explain though (to a newbie)? To help me avoid repeating the same mistake in the future.

Comment: when you answer a question there are a few options for you to make your answer look clearer, like putting the code snippets or any piece of code inside the code block . such highlighted bifurcation of code blocks and plain text makes your answer clear and easy to understand.